# Xcode 4.6: Only Portrait Area Active in Landscape iPad app

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, landscape-portrait, autorotate

I have a landscape only iPad app with loaded ViewControllers whose sizes match the main ViewController of 1024x768. I noticed that, while everything displays properly, any controls set in the rightmost area of my loaded views are inactive to touch. A friend suggested I check to make sure that all of my XIB files were set to “Landscape” orientation in the Attributes inspector. Sure enough, all of my XIBs were set to “Portrait”. I went through the tedious task of setting all of my XIB files (50+) to the following settings:

Attributes Inspector - 
**Size:** None
**Orientation:** Landscape
**Status Bar:** None
**Top Bar:** None
**Bottom Bar:** None
**Mode:** Scale To Fill
**User Interaction Enabled:** Checked
**Drawing/Opaque:** Checked
**Drawing/Autoresize Subviews:** Checked

Size Inspector -
**Show:** Layout Rectangle
**Width:** 1024
**Height:** 768

Everything else is set to default settings.

I’m still having the same problem. Am I missing something? Not sure if this is relevant, but I’m not using storyboards.

Please help.

Thanks

M

Comment: In the Attribute Inspector where you changed the Orientation setting from Portrait to Landscape was under a section called "Simulated Metrics", a very important thing to take note of. You change those settings to simulate their effects on the XIB in Interface Builder, they have no affect on the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with a webView and it turned out I was missing this line:

```
myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```